# Create two arrays and then use them in a third array used as data for a two spinner uipickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Hi I'm trying to create my first IOS app which uses a uiPickerView with two spinners.

From various tutorials I found that the picker data was defined so:

```
var pickerData = [["value1","value2", "value3"],["valueA", "valueB"]]
```

As I have a number of values I thought I would create them dynamically

The code I have is:

```
var poundValues = [String]()
var penceValues = [String]()

for var indexP:Int = 0; indexP < 100; indexP += 1 {
    poundValues.append("£ \(indexP)")
}

for var pindex:Int = 0; pindex < 100; pindex += 1 {
    penceValues.append(".\(pindex)")
}

let pickerData = [poundValues,penceValues]
```

Unfortunately I get compiler error and I can't figure out how to correct. The first error occurs on both the "for var" lines...`Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'` but I do have ;s in place.
The second is on the "let pickerData" line...`'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'poundValues'`

Also in the penceValues I'd like to pad single digits with a leading 0 so that the spinner displays .00 .01 .02 .... .09 .10 .11 etc.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided compiles fine as is, although you can save a second loop since both for loops iterate over the same indices. Also, below is the formatting to pad your single digits.

```
var poundValues = [String]()
var penceValues = [String]()

for var indexP:Int = 0; indexP < 100; indexP += 1 {
    poundValues.append("£ \(indexP)")
    penceValues.append(NSString(format: ".%02d", indexP) as String)
}

let pickerData = [poundValues, penceValues]
```

It would be helpful to see your UIViewController subclass in its entirety to help with the build errors you are seeing.

Comment: Still getting compilation errors... have raised a fresh question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995814/compiler-errors-which-compile-fine-in-playground

Answer (score 0):

I don't have those errors after pasting your code in a playground "as is", so I presume there's something wrong in the code surrounding it - unclosed bracket maybe?

As for your code, you can get rid of the 2 for loops, and simplify it as follows:

```
let poundValues = map(0..<100) { "£ \($0)" }
let penceValues = map(0..<100) { ($0 < 10 ? "0" : "") + "\($0)" }
```

The `penceValues` array contains the first 10 elements with an additional `0` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes your code to break, but wanted to show you an alternative solution. You don't have to create the arrays at all. I assume you are using the array values in the titleForRow method. Instead of using an array, you can generate the values in there:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return "£ \(row)"
        }
        else {
            return String(format: ".%.02d", arguments: [row])
        }
    }
```