# Compiler errors which compile fine in Playground

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code which if checked in playground complies OK (apart from the functions triggered by actions)... yet in my application I'm getting 7 compilation errors.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class LocationViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var DisplayStartMileage: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelFuelAmount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView!

var mileageToPass: String!

var fuelAmount: Double = 0.00

var poundValues = [String]()
var penceValues = [String]()

for var indexP:Int = 0; indexP < 100; indexP += 1 {
poundValues.append("£ \(indexP)")
penceValues.append(NSString(format: ".%02d", indexP) as String)
}

let pickerData = [poundValues, penceValues]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    DisplayStartMileage.text = mileageToPass;

    spinFuelAmount.delegate = self
    spinFuelAmount.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func FuelSegmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        labelFuelAmount.hidden = false
        spinFuelAmount.hidden = false

    case 1:
        labelFuelAmount.hidden = true
        spinFuelAmount.hidden = true

    default:
        break; 
    }

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}

func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerData[component][row]
}

func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let fuelAmount = Int(pickerData[0][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(0)].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("£ ", withString: "")) + Int(pickerData[1][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(1)].stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString(".", withString: ""))/100

}
```

}

Now I know that SO is not for debugging but I am at a loss... most of the code complies in Playground and yet many of the lines that do complied in Playground error in my ViewController Class.

Comment: Move your code inside viewDidLoad

Comment: This code does not compile in a Playground  either.

Comment: *What* seven errors? Those errors contain useful information about what's wrong.

Comment: Importing Foundation might help, depending on the errors, which as Tom says you should certainly post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ditch the `poundValues` and `penceValues` as member properties and set up all this stuff in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
var pickerData = [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    DisplayStartMileage.text = mileageToPass;

    var poundValues = [String]()
    var penceValues = [String]()
    for var indexP:Int = 0; indexP < 100; indexP += 1 {
        poundValues.append("£ \(indexP)")
        penceValues.append(NSString(format: ".%02d", indexP) as String)
    }
    self.pickerData = [poundValues, penceValues]

    spinFuelAmount.delegate = self
    spinFuelAmount.dataSource = self
}
```

**Update**

Here's a suggestion for that `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent)` method:

```
func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var firstComponent = pickerData[0][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    firstComponent = firstComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "£ ", withString: "" )

    var secondComponent = pickerData[1][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
    secondComponent = firstComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "£ ", withString: "" )

    if let firstValue = Int(firstComponent), let secondValue = Int(secondComponent) {
        let fuelAmount = firstValue + secondValue / 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Great - worked a treat. Now need to look at my didSelectRow function...the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method is not recognised...

Comment: I added an update to address that.  It's best to avoid packing too much into one line like that.  It makes it very hard to read and understand what's going on and to detect any errors.  Spreading it out into its individual steps is much clearer.

Comment: Patrick thanks... I've updated your code as there was a bit of cut and paste for secondComponent. Unfortunately I'm still getting an error Cannot find initialiser for type Int that accepts an argument list of type string.... any ideas?

Comment: My code is Swift 2.0, you must be working in 1.2.  Use `firstComponent.toInt()` instead of `Int(firstComponent)`.

Comment: Thanks .toInt() did it.